# Mapping Parameters from a Database in Anylogic

Tags: parameters, dataset, anylogic, modeling

I'm trying to map patient parameters but the columns from the database I imported do not appear. Also, the selected parameter is not shown in the parameter dropdown list, only other parameters are shown.[Properties of Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHIgv.png)  [Patient Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfasO.png)

Could it be that the dataset needs to be reimported or in a different format?

Answer (score 0):

First, the Parameter value editor section (with the dropdown in your 2nd screenshot) is entirely irrelevant here. It is used for something completely different (i.e. ignore)

To solve your problem, ensure to setup your source such that it creates `Patient` agents:
[image]

In your `Patient` agent, ensure to have a `p_Name` of type String and in your dbase table, ensure the column is also of type string and of you go

Comment: The source creates patients agents but i do not have the window for agent parameters mapping.

Comment: did you select to set agent params from db?

Comment: yes, but I have two sources, could it be that the mappings are in the first source only? (because this source I'm unable to open its an error when i try to)

Comment: see reply in other issue

Comment: i was able to remove the source from the project tree and add a new one. However, the agent parameters mapping is still not there could it be due to using the PLE version?